# cant get Subtitle to Echo, only Title

Tags: php, title, subtitle

I am having trouble using `<?php echo $subtitle; ?>`

I am using this to set the subtitles and main title

```
<?php   $title = "Main Title";
        $subtitle = "Sub Title";
        $output = str_replace('%TITLE%', $title, $subtitle, $output);
        echo $output;
?>
```

using `<?php echo $title; ?>` always returns the correct value, but the Subtitle is always returned blank

Comment: Show real code, this one works - https://3v4l.org/EqOPO

Comment: yeah it always works fine in code checkers, where it doesn't work is on my website, with only echo $title working and not $subtitle or $output

Comment: It looks like you misunderstand how `str_replace` work. In your example code it looks for '%TITLE%' text in `$subtitle` and try to replace it with `$title` value. But because it didn't find '%TITLE%' it always return original `$subtitle` value. So it just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also putting $output as last parameter to str_replace is a mistake, unless you want to cast some string to 1 or 0. But I believe you don't.

Comment: so I should delete all references to Subtitle and make anew variable called $pname for example to stop any error

Answer (score 0):

removing all mentions of `$subtitle` and renaming the variable as `$pname` with out using the `str_replace` worked, thank you for the tip, I am going to have to learn more about that function